# Taking a part of my php array into a textbox

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have an external JSON file(with variable content).
example: http://api.pstcd.nl/range/?auth_key=p5C6FsEl6O1vTXAznIOj&fourpp=4205&range=5&transposing=1

JSON data:

```
{
  "status": "ok",
  "total": 4,
  "results": 
  {
    "distance": 
    [
      0,
      0.925,
      0.936,
      1.026,
      1.177,
      1.443,
      1.511,
      2.081,
      2.816,
      3.105,
      3.108,
      3.145,
      3.346,
      3.392,
      3.547,
      3.616,
      3.866,
      3.875,
      4.027,
      4.186
    ],
    "lng": 
    [
      4.9663,
      4.9551,
      4.9667,
      4.9812,
      4.9581,
      4.9752,
      4.9515,
      4.9946,
      4.9255,
      4.9497,
      4.9933,
      5.009,
      5.0122,
      5.01,
      5.0125,
      5,
      4.9968,
      4.9733,
      4.9746,
      4.9456
    ],
    "lat": 
    [
      51.8417,
      51.8371,
      51.8333,
      51.8413,
      51.8325,
      51.83,
      51.8317,
      51.8352,
      51.8439,
      51.8158,
      51.8641,
      51.8518,
      51.8319,
      51.8276,
      51.8559,
      51.8667,
      51.8126,
      51.8763,
      51.8776,
      51.8771
    ],
    "fourpp": 
    [
      "4205",
      "4204",
      "4200",
      "4206",
      "4203",
      "4201",
      "4202",
      "4207",
      "4209",
      "4254",
      "4241",
      "4212",
      "4208",
      "4213",
      "4211",
      "4240",
      "4285",
      "4220",
      "4221",
      "4223"
    ]
  }
}
```

(Thanks to the editor for putting this in)
Its contents need to be partly used and put in a label or textbox.

My php code so far is:

```
$json = file_get_contents('http://api.pstcd.nl/range/?auth_key=p5C6FsEl6O1vTXAznIOj&fourpp=' . $postcode . '&range=' . $range . '&transposing=1');
$data = json_decode($json, TRUE);

print_r($data);
```

The part that I need to take out is the results after `fourpp`.

Anyone know how to get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data after `fourpp` is an array, so you can loop over it with `foreach`.

```
foreach ($data['results']['fourpp'] as $item) {
    echo "<input type='text' value='$item'>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `foreach`

```
  foreach($data as $key => $val)
  {
    $result = $val['fourapp'];
  }
   print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$postcode = 4205;
$range = 5;
$json = file_get_contents('http://api.pstcd.nl/range/?auth_key=p5C6FsEl6O1vTXAznIOj&fourpp=' . $postcode . '&range=' . $range . '&transposing=1');
$data = json_decode($json, TRUE);

if(isset($data['status']) && $data['status'] ==  'ok' && isset($data['results']['fourpp'])){
    $fourpp_data = $data['results']['fourpp'];
}

print_r($fourpp_data);

foreach($fourpp_data as $this_data){
    echo sprintf('<input type="text" value="%s">', $this_data); 
}
```

simple array